# IE document mode

Tags: internet-explorer-8, x-ua-compatible

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,chrome=1" />
```

i've put this between my `<head></head>`
it works in my IE(11),
but my client who uses IE(8),the document mode always use ie7,
and all the other in his company who uses IE8 show the same problem too, not just him.

i saw some people say using`content="IE=edge"`is a way
but i can't ,i must use  `content="IE=8"`to run other thing... 
is there any way to fix it? to make the browser used document mode in ie8?

Comment: Try `content="IE=EmulateIE8"` and/or using a semi-colon instead of a colon to separate chrome.

Comment: i've change it to`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8 ; chrome=1" /> `but still not working....